# Why doesn't it work without the car-back class?

Tags: html, css

I found a solution to my problem but, I can't wrap my head around why this works. Why would I need the class car-back when my id image has the same code? If I take out the class car-back it no longer stretches my image like I want it to. All I really need is an explanation why I need the class car-back.

Here is my html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initail-scale = "1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="image">
    <img src="WP_20131026_007.jpg" alt="" class="car-back">
    </div>
    <p>This should be poppins</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

my css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200i,400&display=swap');

body{
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-weight: 200 !important;
  /*max-width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}
#image{
  width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}
 .car-back{
   width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }
```

Comment: `.car-back` is on the `<img>` and `#image` is on the `<div>`. They are different elements.

Answer (score 0):

`#image` is the *container* of the `.car-back` image. The `#image` settings apply only to that container.

`width` and `heigth` of `.car-back` (both 100%) are *relative* to its *container* , i.e. to `#image`.

*Without* the `.car-back` class and its particular settings, the `.car-back` image would be displayed at its original size instead of being 100% width and heigth of its container.